# normalScrollElements in fullpage.js does not accept multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, fullpage.js

In the [fullpage.js spec](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) under `normalscrollElements` it states I can list `X` number JQuery selectors as a comma separated string.

So this is how I currently have it configured:

```
 $('#fullpage_2').fullpage({
  anchors:['info', 'lists', 'activity','stats','valorations','forum-stats'],
  menu: '#fp-nav',

  scrollingSpeed: 700,
  normalScrollElements: '#prueba6, #searchbox',

  scrollOverflow:true,
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    var loadedSection = $(this);

    console.log("el indice es: "+index);

    //using anchorLink

  }

});
```

However it does not work for multiple selectors. The strange part is, I can put the below code and it works:

```
normalScrollElements: '#prueba6',
```

or I can put:

```
normalScrollElements: '#searchbox',
```

But as soon as I put the two together, `normalScrollElements: '#prueba6, #searchbox'`, it only works for the **first element (`#prueba6`)**. How can I bind to more than one element?

Comment: According to the spec, your implementation is correct. `normalScrollElements: (default null) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the jQuery selectors for those elements.` **  `(For example: normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2').` ** `This option should not be applied to any section/slide element itself.` https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/.

Comment: Yeah I know I followed the guide but the problem that only works with one element. If tomorrow I want add the #prueba7 to the below elements I can, I have to choose only one

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Nop 0. Onlye works the first element that I put, I I put before prueba6 works that, and not searchbox. If I put before searchbox, work this not prueba6. But not at the same time. But any console error.

Answer (score 0):

Working perfectly as expected. See this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5yLsdwmt/22/

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange'],
  normalScrollElements: '#demo1, #demo2'
});
```

You are probably doing something wrong. But because you did not provide an isolated reproduction, we can not help you.

Reading this topic should help you with questions :)
https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/how-not-suck-at-asking-coding-questions/